# comparing two exactly same timestamp data, but showing false

Tags: python, dataframe, timestamp

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWeUt.png)

I have taken some timestamp data from two different dataframe, and tried to compare them.
However, even though the timestamp data are exactly same, python is returning false.
(please refer to the screenshot)

what am I doing wrong?

Source:

```
if covid_traffic_data.at[22, '시점'] is covid_confirmed_data.at[1, 'date']:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)

print(covid_traffic_data.at[22, '시점'])
print(covid_confirmed_data.at[1, 'date'])
```

Result:

```
False
2020-01-23 00:00:00
2020-01-23 00:00:00
```

Comment: You should use `==` to test for equality. `is` tests for object identity.

Answer (score 1):

`is` compares object references. It will return True only if both variables point to the same place in memory. On the other hand,
`==` uses whatever implementation of `__eq__` object has or defaults to `is` if `__eq__` is not implemented for that class.

Comment: for goodness' sake.. I was too excited to learn python and couldn't stop using 'is'.. Thank you!